# How do you sync a progress bar to data?

Tags: java, progress-bar, swt

My program reads files from a directory on the filesystem. I have a progress bar that has minimum set to `0` and a maximum set to `n`(number of files in particular directory). Above it is a piece of text which displays the progress of the iterations... `1/100, 2/100, 3/100` etc.

The problem I'm having is the text displayed is never in sync with the progress bar. The progress bar will be at around `70%` when the text says `100/100`. Can anybody help me with this?

```
pb1.setMinimum(0);
pb1.setMaximum(files2.size());

shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (pb1.isDisposed()) return;
        for(final File f : files2) {
            pb1.setSelection(pb1.getSelection() + 1);
            dialogShell.setText("Loading" + pb1.getSelection() +
                "/"+pb1.getMaximum());

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using a 'counter' in your thread like

```
pb1.setMinimum(0);
pb1.setMaximum(files2.size());

shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int n = pb1.getMinimum();
        int d = pb1.getMaximum();

        if (pb1.isDisposed()) { return; }

        for(final File f:files2){
            pb1.setSelection(n);
            dialogShell.setText("Loading "+n+"/"+d);
            n++;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work properly. Is there a reason why the progress bar, when initially set to 50%, still takes a second to display the bar up to that point? I think it may be just the lag of this animation that's causing my problem.

Comment: try `syncExec` instead of `asyncExec`, asyncExec doesn't wait for the UI to 'update' where as syncExec will